# How do I use regex to replace something between parentheses?

Tags: regex

For example suppose I have the following string

"we went to the (big) zoo"

I would like to match and replace the text between the parentheses and also catch one of the extra white spaces to end up with

"we went to the zoo"

What is the syntax to do this?  I can't seem to quite get it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to a global search of `\s*\([^)]\)\s*` replacing each occurrence with a single space. Exactly how you would code this depends on what language you are using.

In Perl it would look like

```perl
my $s = "we went to the (big) zoo";

$s =~ s/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/ /g;

print $s;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
we went to the zoo
```

Answer (score 2):

In `VIM` you can type command:

```
%s/([[:alpha:]]*)\ //g
```

This would do it all globally (`g` stands for global replacement, you can put `1` for intance and it'd do it only once per line).
If you are using `sed`, then it be similar. Something along the lines of:

```
cat input.txt | sed s/([[:alpha:]]*)\ //g
```

Note that here I'd used `[[:alpha:]]` for char strings only. If you use `.*`, then it'd be for any characters (including numbers, white spaces, non-printable chars, etc)...

Answer (score 1):

You can to detect the parentheses (`/\(.*?*\)/`) and remove them.

Which are language you write?

Comment: `[^)]` would be more efficient than `.*?`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the regex will look something like this:

```
/\((.*?)\)/
```

But as the comments suggest, the language and application may affect this.